# Error while running Hive Action in Oozie

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive, oozie

I'm trying to run a hive action through Oozie. My `workflow.xml` is as follows:

```
<workflow-app name='edu-apollogrp-dfe' xmlns="uri:oozie:workflow:0.1">
    <start to="HiveEvent"/>
    <action name="HiveEvent">
            <hive xmlns="uri:oozie:hive-action:0.2">
                    <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
                    <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
                    <configuration>
                            <property>
                                    <name>oozie.hive.defaults</name>
                                    <value>${hiveConfigDefaultXml}</value>
                            </property>
                    </configuration>
                    <script>${hiveQuery}</script>
                    <param>OUTPUT=${StagingDir}</param>
            </hive>

            <ok to="end"/>
            <error to="end"/>
    </action>

    <kill name='kill'>
                    <message>Hive failed, error message[${wf:errorMessage(wf:lastErrorNode())}]</message>
    </kill>
    <end name='end'/>
```

And here is my job.properties file:

```
oozie.wf.application.path=${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/hiveQuery
oozie.libpath=${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/hiveQuery/lib
queueName=interactive

#QA
nameNode=hdfs://hdfs.bravo.hadoop.apollogrp.edu
jobTracker=mapred.bravo.hadoop.apollogrp.edu:8021

# Hive

hiveConfigDefaultXml=/etc/hive/conf/hive-default.xml

hiveQuery=hiveQuery.hql
StagingDir=${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/hiveQuery/Output
```

When I run this workflow, I end up with this error:

```
ACTION[0126944-130726213131121-oozie-oozi-W@HiveEvent] Launcher exception: org/apache/hadoop/hive/cli/CliDriver
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/hive/cli/CliDriver
```

`Error Code: JA018`

`Error Message: org/apache/hadoop/hive/cli/CliDriver`

I'm not sure what this error means. Where am I going wrong?

**EDIT**

[This link](http://archive.cloudera.com/cdh4/cdh/4/oozie/oozie-default.xml) says error code `JA018` is: `JA018 is output directory exists error in workflow map-reduce action`. But in my case the output directory does not exist. This makes it all the more confusing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I figured out what was going wrong!

The class `org/apache/hadoop/hive/cli/CliDriver` is required for execution of a Hive Action. This much is obvious from the error message. This class is within this jar file: `hive-cli-0.7.1-cdh3u5.jar`. (In my case cdh3u5 in my cloudera version).

Oozie checks for this jar in the `ShareLib` directory. The location of this directory is usually configured in `hive-site.xml`, with the property name as `oozie.service.WorkflowAppService.system.libpath`, so Oozie should find the jar easily.

But in my case, `hive-site.xml` did not include this property, so Oozie didn't know where to look for this jar, hence the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError`.

To resolve this, I had to include a parameter in my job.properties file to point oozie to the location of the `ShareLib` directory, as follows:
`oozie.libpath=${nameNode}/user/oozie/share/lib`. (depends on where `SharedLib` directory is configured on your cluster).

This got rid of the error!